# Is the "Match-3" mechanic unpatented?

Tags: game-mechanics, patents

Can I use a match-3 mechanic in my commercial game without being sued by some company holding the patent? I will add some extra features to the mechanic.

Comment: There are a ton of match 3 games and I'm guessing they aren't all made by the same company... So yes... Yes you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our [*Ask Patents* sister site](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) have a more general question: [*Can game mechanics be patented?*](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/210/can-game-mechanics-be-patented) It seems most mechanics *are* patentable, but only very specifically. (This may be different for your country.)

I'm no lawyer, but based on those answers, I believe you'll be fine, provided your "some extra features" are significant enough extensions to make your game distinctly differ from the patent.

With English search terms, I found [this US patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130331162?dq=match+three&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9B8TU73rDbDb7AaDo4D4Bg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA) titled *Match three gaming system and method* through [Google Patent Search](https://www.google.com/?tbm=pts). The idea seems unpatented in the UK. (You should check your own country's patent registry of course.)

Comment: Thank you for your great comment ) There's more than enough information for me.